# Семантика глагольных приставок

Tags: грамматика

Почему приставки глаголов так важны для смысла предложения? Как я понимаю, не будет разницы, если я скажу: 
«Поезд отошёл от станции», или «Поезд шёл от станции».

Как они отличаются друг от друга?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приставки в русском языке часто выполняют двойную функцию: образуют совершенный вид глагола и задают направление действия этого глагола:

1) Поезд отошел от станции: событие совершилось, задано направление движения.

2) Поезд шёл от станции А к станции Б (когда, к примеру,  произошло событие N). Событие совершалось в определенный момент в прошлом.

Так что два приведенных варианта различаются между собой существенным образом.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информаю)))

Answer (score 0):

В русском нет многих грамматических глагольных форм из других языков, приставки это компенсируют. И еще

В данном случае это грамматически разные вещи (что делал и что уже сделал), первое обычно соответствует прошедшему времени (на английском - обычному или продолженному), второе - разным вариантам перфекта. А значение в чем-то действительно близко. Но разница есть, как минимум в том, что *в первом случае поезд шел именно от станции, а не из депо, например, или что не к станции шел, а от неё*. А вот во втором - смысл один и конкретный. *Уже отошел от станции*. Свершилось! Какой-то этап. Стоянка закончена, провожающие вышли из вагонов, можно пользоваться туалетом, отставшие и опоздавшие могут догонять самолётом или менять билеты. Т.е. есть существенная информация именно в том, что отошел.

Да, это всего лишь смысловые акценты, но в русском они очень важны, поскольку почти всегда содержат информацию, значимую. для повествующего и слушающего.

Но вообще подобные случаи редки, обычно приставка модифицирует глагол не только по грамматическому виду, но и существенно сказываются на смысле. Обычно приставка позволяет более точно назвать действие (отбил, забил, прибил - это все разные по смыслы значения, хотя и связаны с "бить") или вообще придает совершенно другой смысл (убил, разбил - эти напрямую с битьем даже не связаны).

Comment: Отлично! Теперь все ясно. Спасибо!